# jQuery calculation plugin: show total in form field rather than text

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm embarrassed by the 'basicness' of this question, but after wasted hours, here goes.

In an effort to do something with the jQuery Calculation plugin, I am playing with the basic example of the order form on the [plugin site](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm). I want to have the grand total as a form field,rather than text, so I can use the value.

The function that calculates and shows the grand total is:

```
    function ($this){
                // sum the total of the $("[id^=total_item]") selector
                var sum = $this.sum();

                $("#grandTotal").text(
                    // round the results to 2 digits
                    sum.toFixed(2)
                );
            }
```

the total updates on keyup in:

```
<span id="grandTotal"></span>
```

But this does not work with:

```
<input type="text" id="grandTotal" value=""/>
```

Can anyone point me to what I need to add/change to make that work? To call my javascript basic would be a compliment, so please talk to me like I know nothing!

Comment: Embarrassed?  Why?  Everyone has "basic" questions when they're learning a new topic. All of us have been there....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the value of input fields with jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$("#grandTotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

---

Just to be complete: If you have a `textarea`, then you can set the text inside the textarea with the `.text()` method (I am not sure about `.val()` though, I think this really only works on the other form elements).

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for not calling me an idiot :) Ditto to everyone else.

Comment: @Katherine: What do you think *my* problems were at the beginning? There is always a start, good if someone else helps you. Btw you should accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ($this){ 
            // sum the total of the $("[id^=total_item]") selector 
            var sum = $this.sum(); 

            $("#grandTotal").val( 
                // round the results to 2 digits 
                sum.toFixed(2) 
            ); 
        }
```

Try that.

change `.text` to `.val`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `val` method to insert value into the textbox:

```
$("#grandTotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```